# How to combine Ivy and Artifactory (plus Jenkins)?

Tags: jenkins, ivy, artifactory

I'm trying to upgrade librarires and artifacts management in my company. Now we're making artifacts (jar, war, ear files) with ant scripts running from Jenkins. I'd like to add Ivy and Artifactory but I'm a little bit unsure what would be best (or at leats good) configuration. As per [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/defaultconf.html),
Ivy has three repositories (local, shared and public) and additionaly cache. Reading [Artifactory docs](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Ivy), one has to configure Ivy files for Artifactory resolver (not repository?!).
My questions are:

1. Would that be public repository in Ivy terminology?
2. Is Ok tu use only one Artifactory repository for development (we have 4 teams) and deployment pipeline?
3. What would be (approximate) configuration? Is this ok (public ibiblio + enterprise Artifactory)?

   ```
   <resolvers>
       <ibiblio name="libraries" m2compatible="true" />
       <url name="arti">
           <artifact pattern="http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
           <ivy pattern="http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
       </url>
   </resolvers>
   ```

***Update on 11th Feb***:
Just for the record, here is working configuration:

```
<credentials host="artifactory.host" realm="Artifactory Realm" username="admin" passwd="password"/>

<resolvers>
    <chain name="loc-ext">
    <filesystem name="tmp-lib">
        <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/lib/[artifact].[ext]" />
    </filesystem>
    <ibiblio name="libraries"
        m2compatible="true"
        checkmodified="true"
        root="http://artifactory.host:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local" 
    />
    </chain>

    <ibiblio name="snapshots"
        m2compatible="true"
        pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
        root="http://artifactory.host:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local"
    />
</resolvers>
```

Chain resolver is for retrieving (f.e. for compiling), **tmp_lib** has libraries, that are needed only for current task, **libraries** is sort of enterprise repository and **snapshots** is for publishing.

Answer (score 2):

We us Artifactory, Jenkins, and Ivy to build most or our projects, but I probably am doing it all wrong.

First, we don't bother with a *shared* repository. It never made much sense to me. The shared repo looks similar to the *private* repo, but is shared among developers. What makes that so different from a Artifactory repository that's only shared among the developers?

We also use `<ivy:makepom>` to create a `pom.xml` and then use `mvn deploy` to deploy our artifacts to our Artifactory repo instead of using the `<ivy:publish>`. We make two poms per jar, one is `pom.xml` and the other is `pom-snapshot.xml`. We use Jenkin's Build Promotion Plugin to run `mvn deploy` with each successful build to deploy the snapshot jar, and then let developers manually "promote a build" via the Build Promotion Plugin to deploy the *release* version of the jar.

Ivy has the concept of [status](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/terminology.html#status) which looks similar to the snapshot vs. release idea of Maven, but I believe that all these jars with their status are deployed to the same repo. I simply keep the status set to *release* and depend upon the snapshot/release concept in Maven.

Developers can switch from snapshot versions of a jar to the release version by simply appending or removing `-SNAPSHOT` from the revision in `ivy.xml`. This allows developers to use recently built jars without waiting for them to be promoted to the *release* repository.

My main concern was keeping Artifactory compatible with Maven since some of our projects are Maven projects. Some of this was due to not being 100% familiar with Ivy, and having a firmer grasp with Maven. However, it does work for us and keeps me from worrying about the differences between Ivy and Maven.

Now, that you know we're doing it all wrong, here are the answers to your question:

> 1. Would that be public repository in Ivy terminology?

Ivy has the concept of [status](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/terminology.html#status), but I'm not sure how a Maven project could use that. This is why we use `mvn deploy` and why we build a snapshot and release pom with each build.

> 1. Is Ok tu use only one Artifactory repository for development (we have 4 teams) and deployment pipeline?

Sure, why not? What would be the advantage of making four separate repositories. Besides, even if you go with the separate repositories, you could create them all with a single Artifactory instance. This way, you could assign read/write permissions to each group for each of their repos, but only have to maintain a single Artifactory instance.

> 1. What would be (approximate) configuration? Is this ok (public ibiblio + enterprise Artifactory)?

Ours is:

```
<ivysettings>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="public"
            m2compatible="true"
            checkmodified="true"
            root="http://buildl01.tcprod.local/artifactory/libs-release" />
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

But we're not deploying as Ivy. Just reading from a *Maven* repo. The `libs-release` is a virtual repo with includes our local repo and the public repos from Maven, JBoss, and whatever repos we need.

I have a special `ivy.dir` project that automatically integrates Ivy into our builds. You add in `<import file="${ivy.dir}/ivy.tasks.xml"/> into your build, and you automatically have all the necessary Ivy settings. I also create several parallel macros such as`` that are drop in replacements with the standard Ant tasks, but do a few mysterious things behind the scenes.

For example `<jar.macro>` creates a `pom.xml`, a `pom-snapshot.xml`, and embeds the Maven info (plus the Jenkins build info) into the jar. This way, developers could start to integrate Ivy into their build process with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: +1 I'm using Nexus, but adopting the same approach. I don't use the "local" and "shared" ivy repositories. If it's not published to my Maven repository it doesn't exist :-)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor - You probably use the _local_ repository because that's where all jars are downloaded in order to run tasks like `<ivy:cachepath>` and `<ivy:retrieve>`. It's sort of the cache Ivy uses, so its not constantly downloading jars. It's stored in `$HOME/.ivy2/cache` by default much like Maven's cache is `$HOME/.m2/repository`.

Comment: You are correct to point out that ivy caches files, but this is not the same as the "local" and "shared" repoositories. The Maven client uses its local repository as a cache. Ivy on the other hand, has defaults that allow you to publish to a "local" or "shared" resolver. These by default will save files under "~/.ivy2/local" and "~/.ivy2/shared". As stated I prefer to avoid confusion and publish my files to a managed Maven repository. This means I always provide an ivysettings file to override the default settings.